# How to use akka as a replication mechanism

Tags: akka

I'm new to akka and intend to use it in my new project as a data replication mechanism.

In this scenario, there is a master server and a replicate data server. The replicate data should contain the same data as the master. Each time a data change occurred in the master, it sends an update message to the replicate server. Here the master server is the Sender, and the Replicate server is the Receiver.

But after digging the docs I'm still not sure how to satisfy the following use cases:

- When the receiver crashes, the sender should pile up messages to send, none messages should be lost. It should be able to reconnect to the receiver later and continue with last successful message.
- when the sender crashes, it should restart and no messages between restart is lost.
- Messages are dealt with the same order they were sent.

So my question is, how to config akka to create a sender and a receiver that could do this?

I'm not sure actor with a DurableMessageBox could solve this. If it could, how can i  simulate the above situations for testing?

**Update:**

After reading the docs Victor pointed at, I now got the point that what I wanted was **once-and-only-once** pattern, which is extremely costly.

In the akka docs it says

> Actual transports may provide stronger semantics, but **at-most-once** is the semantics you should expect. The alternatives would be **once-and-only-once**, which is extremely costly, or **at-least-once** which essentially requires idempotency of message processing, which is a user-level concern.

So inorder to achieve Guaranteed Delivery, I may need to turn to some other MQ solution (for example [Kafka](http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/design.html)), or try to implement **once-and-only-once** with DurableMessageBox, and see if the complexity with it could be relieved with my specific use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write your own remoting that utilizes the durable subscriber pattern, as Akka message send guarantees are less strict than what you are going for: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/general/message-send-semantics.html

Cheers,
√